# Convert from music21 stream to vexflow script code

Tags: javascript, python, music21, vexflow

It seems the music21 python package is able to show music notation, but does not allow me to view the script generated through the music21j library. All I am able to see are the Python streams in detail, but not the Javascript script that uses Vexflow? How can I see the source code the music21 package generates when I execute its vexflow converter?

Comment: the relevant commands are in the vexflow submodule of music21 -- I'll try to expand more with an answer below, but this should give a start of where to look.